# Bash Function Components Working Independently but Not Together

Tags: bash, function, grep, vi

I have a bash script that has this function in it:

```
function start_vi()
{
   echo "Please enter a file name with complete path to open in vi:"
   read input_file

   if [ -d "$input_file" ]
   then
      echo "You entered a directory."
      echo "Please try again and enter a readable/writable file."
   fi

   grep_var="file $input_file | grep -c data"

   if [ $? -eq 0 ]
   then
      vi $input_file
   else
      echo "File not found or invalid file type. Please try again."
   fi
}
```

For the most part the function works fine.  My problem is that the two if statements work fine independently, eg, if I comment out one of them, the test works and it does what I want.  But together, as written, for example, when I type in a directory at the prompt, vi opens it as a file, where the test should return an echo saying that it's a directory, as it does when functioning alone.

Any ideas on why this is?  I'm still relatively new at bash scripting so it is probably easy for the pros, but I have been banging my head against the wall for a while now.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `return` statement in the first `if/then`:

```
function start_vi()
{
   echo "Please enter a file name with complete path to open in vi:"
   read input_file

   if [ -d "$input_file" ]
   then
      echo "You entered a directory."
      echo "Please try again and enter a readable/writable file."
      return
   fi

   grep_var="file $input_file | grep -c data"

   if [ $? -eq 0 ]
   then
      vi $input_file
   else
      echo "File not found or invalid file type. Please try again."
   fi
}
```

Otherwise, it will print and then open the file anyway, as your second test should be like this:

```
   file $input_file | grep -c data

   if [ $? -eq 0 ]
```

The `$?` is the exit code of the last run command. Assigning to a variable (i.e. `grep_var="..."`) sets `$?` to 0. What you seem to have wanted is the exit code of `grep -c data` - in that case, use backticks ` instead of quotes " to run commands, like below. Or you can write it like this:

```
   grep_var=`file $input_file | grep -c data`

   if [ $grep_var != 0 ]
```

to compare the string value (i.e. what `grep -c data` returns - the count of `data` lines).

Doing some of the above should solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the good advice.  The return worked well, and did exactly what I wanted.  Oddly, adding the tick marks and doing the `$grep_var != 0` test failed to give me results when I entered a valid file, like another shell script.  So I went back to how I had it (with your return) and it is working how I want it.

Comment: Strange - this should work as expected. Try this somewhere where you don't have file named `a`: echo hello > a; if [ ` grep -c hello a ` != 0 ]; then echo There is hello; fi

Comment: That printed: `There is hello`.  Perhaps I made an error when coding that part.  I will try again.

Comment: So it's working :) Are you confusing the output of `file` command maybe? If you do `file myscript.sh`, it will (at least on my system - Ubuntu 11.10) print this: `myscript.sh: ASCII text`. If that's what you want, you need to do grep_var=` file $input_file|grep -c "ASCII text"` or something like that.

Comment: Perhaps.  I read somewhere that if a file is "binary" it will return 'data' in the return line so I'm testing for that.  Maybe this is part of my problem?

Comment: Not necessarily - try `file /bin/bash`. It seems to return `data` on files that it doesn't recognize. Running it on a `.png` picture should not return data, for example. I suggest you run `file` on whatever file you are testing and look what it returns, then if the output contains `data` you can continue testing your script.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a loop:

## ....

```
read input_file
while [ ! -f "$input_file" ]
do
      echo "You did not enter a file"
      echo "Please try again and enter a readable/writable file."
      read input_file
done

grep_var="file $input_file | grep -c data"

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  vi $input_file
else
  echo "File not found or invalid file type. Please try again."
fi
```

Comment: I see how this would work, and it makes sense, but when implemented, the echo statements happen but then the script just sites there.  If I hit Enter it opens vi in a blank file.  Not sure if I did something wrong...

Comment: @nicorellius, I think it's better to check it in the loop.

Comment: you need to input a valid filename to break the loop.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  I'm sorry.  This does work well.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You need a loop

```
function start_vi()
{
   echo "Please enter a file name with complete path to open in vi:"
   read input_file

   while [ -d "$input_file" ]
   do
      echo "You entered a directory."
      echo "Please try again and enter a readable/writable file."
      read input_file
   done

   grep_var="file $input_file | grep -c data"

   if [ $? -eq 0 ]
   then
      vi $input_file
   else
      echo "File not found or invalid file type. Please try again."
   fi
}
```

Comment: Same comment applies to this answer.  See above under perreal's answer.  I'd love to see this loop work, but so far the return is getting the job done.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be closer to what you want to do..

```
function start_vi()
{
   echo "Please enter a file name with complete path to open in vi:"
   read input_file
   grep_var=`file $input_file 2>&1 | grep -c data`
   while [ $? -ne 0 ]
   do
      echo "File not found or invalid file type. Please try again."
      read input_file
      grep_var=`file $input_file 2>&1 | grep -c data`
   done
   vi $input_file
}
```